# Windows shutdown for a period then start normal

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, restart

Is there any tool like linux rtcwake in linux for windows 11?

I want to shutdown or sleep the computer for a period of time (for example 2 days), and the (re)start the computer and run an .exe file.

I try windows schedule task to wake up the computer but it doesn't start.

I have enable the wake up timer in power options.
In bios there is no option for asleep - wake up.

Answer (score 0):

I found [TimeComX Basic](https://timecomx.en.uptodown.com/windows) which have a lot of functionallities.

We can schedule a suspend, then after suspend we can schedule wake up, and finally after wake up we can schedule a program to execute!

That's all i need.

I use python pywinauto module to click on the start task button of TimeComX Basic.